# Can't figure out why form won't save to database ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to save a "product" aka pair of glasses to a database with the following data fields-- Name, Lens, Frame, Temple, Accent, Quantity, Photo.

app/controllers/product_controller.rb

```
def create
   @product = Product.create(product_params)

end

# Each pair of glasses has a name, lens, frame, accent, quantity, and picture
def product_params
   params.require(:product).permit(:name, :lens_id, :frame_id, :temple_id, :accent_id, :quantity, :photo)
end
```

app/views/products/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    ....
    <%= f.label :quantity %>
    <%= number_field_tag :quantity, nil, class: 'form-control', min: 1
</div>
```

I can save the record and everything saves to the database except quantity which saves as 'nil'. I can go into the rails console, select that record, and manually add a quantity via the console though... what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your HTML result from the `number_field_tag` and your web server log from the save action?

Comment: you are passing value as `nil`, and you want `min` value to be `1`. how it will save. remove that `min`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a result of the helper tag you are using for `:quantity`. You should be using the form builder helper `number_field` and not the generic `number_field_tag`.

It should look like this:

```
<%= f.number_field :quantity, nil, class: 'form-control', min: 1 %>
```

If this isn't working for you, perhaps due to your version of Rails, you can override the `type` attribute on `text_field` and try:

```
<%= f.text_field :quantity, nil, class: 'form-control', type: :number, min: 1 %>
```

---

If you want to know why, you will need to understand how Rails is building the POST form data. Using the form builder `form_for` you will see that all of the form fields follow the convention `object_class[attribute]`. In your example it'd make `product[name]`, `product[lens_id]`, etc...

By using `number_field_tag` it created an input with the name `quantity` but you need it to be `product[quantity]` so that when you call `Product.create(product_params)` it includes that provided value.

Your code is producing this for the params:

```
 { 
   product:  
   {
     name: '...',
     lens_id: 1
   },
   quantity: 1
 }
```

vs what is expected:

```
{
  product:
  {
    name: '...',
    lens_id: 1,
    quantity: 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up with '<%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control' %>' as it wouldn't accept the other arguments. But once I tested that it worked! Thank you!